# In Visual Mode, why does my GVIM(on MS Windows) switch back to Insert Mode automatically?

Tags: vim

I use GVim on Windows 7.

My problem is: After I press 'v' to start the Visual Mode, I can only use arrow keys to navigate/select. If I try to use some other keys else like 'j', 'k', etc to navigate/select, it automatically switches back to insert mode and inserts the letter I just entered.

For example: the cursor is on the letter 'm' of the word 'parameter'. I press 'viw' to select the word, but GVIM switches back to insert mode when I press 'i' and the word becomes 'paraiweter'

It only happens in GVIM, not in VIM.

Thank you very much!

Karl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that somehow you have set the `'selectmode'` option to include "cmd" (`:help 'selectmode'`). See what the current value is, and what script set that value, with:

```
:verbose set selectmode?
```

Then you can edit that script and remove the "cmd" string.

If for some reason you cannot edit the script (maybe it's a plugin), you can do `set selectmode-=cmd` somewhere afterwards in your config. For example, in the `~/vimfiles/after/plugin` directory, or with an `autocmd VimEnter set selectmode-=cmd`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben! I removed the 'cmd' and the issue fixed! It's been bothering me for a long time. It's also a very good point about the plugin. I'll remember that :) Cheers!